# exporting symbolic matrix on octave to excel

Tags: arrays, excel, matrix, octave, symbolic-math

hello octave/matlab gurus, i have this matrix X that i want to export to excel. the matrix itself is in symbolic matrix. i tried to loop it first then do xlswrite, but in the excel i get 'conjugate' in every cell, how do i write X to excel but it still looks like math products?

```
pkg load symbolic;
pkg load io;
syms a A b B;

%buat matrix dengan cara copas ke []

M = [a  0   0   B   0   0   B   0   0   0   ;
A   A   0   0   B   B   0   0   0   B   ;
A   a   a   0   0   0   0   0   B   b   ;
A   a   A   0   0   0   0   B   b   b   ;
A   A   0   0   B   B   0   0   0   B   ;
a   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
A   A   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
A   a   a   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
A   a   A   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
a   0   0   b   b   B   0   0   0   B   ;
A   A   0   0   B   B   0   0   0   B   ;
A   a   a   0   0   0   0   0   B   b   ;
A   a   A   0   0   0   0   B   b   b   ;
A   A   0   0   B   B   0   0   0   B   ;
0   0   0   b   b   B   0   0   0   B   ;
0   0   0   0   b   B   0   0   0   B   ;
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   B   b   ;
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   B   b   b   ;
a   0   0   B   0   0   B   0   0   0   ;
A   A   0   0   B   b   b   0   0   0   ;
0   0   0   B   0   0   B   0   0   0   ;
0   0   0   0   B   b   b   0   0   0   ];

X = M*M';
l = size(X,1);
k = size(X,2);
f = cell(l,k);
dio = l*k;

for y=1:dio
f(y) = X(y);
%  f(y) = {char(X(y))};
endfor
```

Comment: Please show how you are writing the excel file. What do you mean by conjugate? There is no complex number involved here. By "conjugate", do you mean "transpose"?